# How to quickly open next file in list in the editor using IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

When viewing a file in IDEA's editor (with the focus in the editor), how can I quickly have it open the next file down in the list of files in the project pane?

I can just double click on the next file in the project pane which appears after the file whose contents are currently in the editor but is there a keyboard shortcut? I looked around in the documentation and here but couldn't find such a key combo.

I am motivated to know this because I have a code base I want to just go through quickly, and linearly (in order the files appear in IDEA's project pane) just to check each file for certain criteria which I can only see with my eyes.

Comment: See http://hadihariri.com/2014/06/24/no-tabs-in-intellij-idea/

Comment: @CrazyCoder Thank you that is a tremendously helpful article. However, either I'm blind or there is no exact key sequence for specifically what I asked for it seems?

Comment: Navigation bar is probably the best way to navigate files in sequence from a directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to use the `Find in Path` action for this with a little trick.

First invoke `Find in Path` on the directory you need, e.g. by typing <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>. Do not specify any search text. Select the `File mask` checkbox and type `*` in the file mask text field. You can of course also type another pattern that matches all files you need to see. Now click the `Open in Find Window` button (<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>). This will show all the files matching the file mask in the Find tool window. Now you can navigate them using the `Navigate | Next Occurrence` action (<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd>).